# Custom tableview of search display controller

Tags: ios, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I do not like the tableview comes with the search display controller, as I want to make some kind of pull to refresh/loadmore to the table, so I was wondering if the tableview can be customized?

Comment: Custom tableview ?? what you realy means. You can have customized cells in UITableView and add pagination using third party libraries like SVPullToRefresh!!

Comment: For example I want to add table header view, or table footer view to the search result, can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

This question appears to be answered in [custom-class-for-uisearchdisplaycontrollers-table-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30330057/custom-class-for-uisearchdisplaycontrollers-table-view)

**tl;dr** You can't get UISearchDisplayController to use a custom table view. If you don't need iOS 7 compatibility, use UISearchController instead.