# Custom class for UISearchDisplayController's table view

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I need to make the table view inside the UISearchDisplayController class to be a custom class which extends from `UITableView`.

I'm using this pod: https://github.com/OliverLetterer/SLExpandableTableView, but I can't seem to make it work when using a UISearchBar and search results.

The class I want use for the table view it's called `SLExpandableTableView` and it has several methods and properties which makes subrows work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using `UISearchDisplayController` because you need to support iOS 7?  You also tagged `UISearchController` which is a replacement for `UISearchDisplayController`.

Comment: No, I'm using `UISearchDisplayController`. I will it remove that from tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure that's possible.  I believe the problem is that `UISearchDisplayController` instantiates an internal `UITableView` for its results.  You'd have to subclass and rewrite it to use your custom tableView, but I wouldn't recommend that.

In iOS 8, you can easily use your own (custom) tableView for search results, but it requires you to migrate to the newer `UISearchController`.

Comment: Thanks! If I use `UISearchController` instead of `UISearchDisplayController`, can I support iOS 7 also?

Comment: No, you can't support iOS 7 and use `UISearchController`.  And `UISearchDisplayController` doesn't support a custom tableView.  I would say if it's a new app, to consider that `UISearchController` is the future, and Apple won't be working on `UISearchDisplayController`. But if you need to support iOS 7 and use a custom tableView, you can just use a `UISearchBar` and filter the search results on your own.